# Is Making a Singleton Configuration File Correct?

Tags: php, web

I have created a configuration file which only contains basic config such as paths and url. To avoid multiple instance when declaring the class I made a singleton to make sure that the config file class has only one instance for reusability so I can use it on another class. Is it correct?

And also I also want to avoid to multiple update of variable values if that variable is located on different classes. With this pattern. I can only edit the root path once and all the classes which uses this root path variable is already updated unlike creating a local variable for each classes with same value of root path.

```
class Configuration
{
    private static $instance;
    private $configurations = array( "root_path"         => "C:/xampp/htdocs/essentials",
                                     "root_url"          => "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/essentials",
                                     "global_class_path" => "/resources/scripts/php/global/classes/",
                                     "login_class_path"  => "/resources/scripts/php/login/classes/",
                                     "time_zone"         => "Asia/Manila" );

    /* Get the instance of the class */
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if ( empty( static::$instance ) ) {
            static::$instance = new static();
        }

        return static::$instance;
    }

    /* Prevent creating of new instance if already existed */
    private function __construct() {}

    /* Prevent cloning of instance */
    private function __clone() {}

    /* Prevent unserializing of instance */
    private function __wakeup() {}

    public function getConfiguration( $configuration_id ) {
        return ( ( empty( $this->configurations[ $configuration_id ] ) )
               ? null
               : $this->configurations[ $configuration_id ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it and hated it

Comment: a factory buys you the same thing as a singleton but without all of the jankyness and bad feels

Comment: any suggestions that would management of variables easier. e.g. if i want to update a variable value which is located on different classes i should update all of those classes. unlike the design pattern. i would only change the value of the variable one time.

Comment: you can still have that class but have the factory worry about making sure there is only one instance

Comment: @Mr.Programmer You're now changing your question entirely to cover a much broader scope of problems. This isn't what StackOverflow is for. If you have a different question, please post that as a new question. And make sure you review the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) sections of the help center before you do so.

Answer (score 0):

The question of **corecness** of a solution first requires a deep understanding of the problem that we're trying to solve.

First, let's examine the solution you chose and then we'll look at the problem a little more deeply. A singleton is a design pattern meant to solve one specific problem: **preventing multiple instances of the same class**. This is only useful when creating multiple instances of that class creates a problem that violates the architectural constrains of a system. For example, take thread pools as a typical use case where architecture must impose certain constraints in order to prevent critical failures.

Now, let's examine the problem you're out to solve with this solution by zooming in just a little closer. First, it's important to note that it's quite difficult to impose on PHP's core architecture by creating constraints like the one you pose here. Since PHP always runs the same way, you start with no initialized classes, no defined functions, no defined variables, no shared memory, with every request, then it's actually rather difficult to find yourself in a position where it was not somehow your fault that there is now more than one instance of a class.

You're not actually after preventing more than one instance of the configuration class in order to prevent some critical failure of the system, to be precise. What you're after is preventing yourself from making a mistake when your code becomes too complex.

So what mistakes can you make here? I posit none if your configuration class is read-only. *There should be no scenario when your code makes permanent changes to your loaded configuration at runtime*. So what harm is there in having more than on instance of the class in this case?

The solution simply doesn't solve the underlying problem you're out to solve.

Comment: Should I use this one instead of the one I posted?
<?php
Class Configuration {
$config1 = "ss";
$config2 = "ss";
}
?>

or this one?

<?php
$config1 = "ss";
$config2 = "ss";
?>

Comment: My answer doesn't change. You shouldn't try to use a design pattern doesn't actually address any of the concerns you're really trying to address.

Comment: So I should not use design pattern and use variables only on those classes that needs it? If I use a variable with same value on different classes. example. I use variable a which contains url of a folder and i use a variable with same value on another code. And if i updated the url. I should update all the variables that uses that url. unlike the design pattern. its easy to change a value

Comment: I never mentioned anything about what you _should_ do or _how_ you should do it. I simply answered your question, which was is a singleton a correct solution. The answer is no, since it doesn't solve for the given problem. You're now generalizing this to "_I shouldn't use classes_", which I never said. I also never said what you should do instead. The question of what _should_ I use is just too broad to answer without writing a book for you. This is why my answer is simply focused on addressing the heart of your question. ___Singletons don't solve the problem you're out to solve___.